# How can I list Media Files from a specific directory in Android 11?

Tags: java, android

I have an app that provides features like Saving WhatsApp Statuses and provide an organized WhatsApp Gallery, along with a few other funtionalites. Right now I'm targeting API 29 with `requestLegacyExternalStorage=true` (having Full File Access). However, I want to migrate to Android 11 but Google has sent a notice that not all apps can have `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`(Full File Access) in their manifest and they are subject to approval.

Hence, I want to access folders like `WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses` and `WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images` in Android 11 without using `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` flag.

I believe that SHAREABLE MEDIA that is contributed by any app to the system can be read without full access (If so then I can retain at least WhatsApp Gallery functionality). Here's the function that I'm using to read IMAGE FILES that doesn't work on Android 11 devices.

```
    private void fetchImages() {
        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals("mounted")) {
            this.file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Whatsapp/Media/Whatsapp Images/" + File.separator);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error! No SDCARD Found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (this.file.isDirectory()) {
            FilePathStrings = new ArrayList();
            this.listFile = this.file.listFiles();
            if (this.listFile != null) {
                for (File value : this.listFile) {
                    String filepath = value.getAbsolutePath();
                    this.fileNames = value.getName();

                    Log.d("FileName", this.fileNames);
                    if (this.fileNames.endsWith(".jpg") || this.fileNames.endsWith(".jpeg") || this.fileNames.endsWith(".png") || this.fileNames.endsWith(".gif")) {
                        FileModels fileModel = new FileModels();
                        fileModel.setImageFilePath(filepath);
                        fileModel.setImageFileName(this.fileNames);
                        fileModel.setImageChecked(Boolean.FALSE);
                        FilePathStrings.add(fileModel);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As I'm still struggling with the `Mediastore` and `Storage Access Framework`, I've used `File` API in above code.

Comment: Storage Access Framework

Comment: @blackapps Thank you for the comment. Is it possible to list the contents of .Statuses with Storage Access Framework? If so, would you mind dropping any reference for the same.

Comment: ACTION_OPENDICUMENT_TREE.